# How to set div width to full without content?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

The Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div{border:solid 1px gray;}
        #mainDiv
        {
            width:300px;
        }
        .leftDiv
        {
            display:table-cell;
            width:50%;
        }
        .rightDiv
        {
            display:table-cell;
            width:50%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainDiv">
         <div class="titleDiv">
            ...titleDiv content...
         <div>
         <div class="leftDiv">
            ...leftDiv content...
         </div>
         <div class="rightDiv">
            ...rightDiv content...
         </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem am having is the `leftDiv` and `rightDiv` only reach their full width if there is enough content in them to do so.

This is a problem for me because i want to play only one word in `leftDiv` and align it to the right.

Comment: Why are you setting display:table-cell for those DIVs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div{border:solid 1px gray;}
        #mainDiv
        {
            width:300px; 
            overflow:auto;
        }
        .float
        {
            float:left;
            width:50%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mainDiv">
         <div class="titleDiv">
            ...titleDiv content...
         <div>
         <div class="float">
            ...leftDiv content...
         </div>
         <div class="float">
            ...rightDiv content...
         </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1: note: the border makes the floated divs not fit, but if you take out the border then the solution works.

Comment: @Sebastian Yes. My solution in such a situation is (generally) to define a px width on the floated DIVs, which would be 148px in this case...

Comment: Or you can stick a negative margin on the divs, or even add a `box-sizing: border-box` to them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
text-align:right
```